# Popup scrolling Issue in Google AppMaker

Tags: scroll, popup, google-app-maker

Can I scroll custom popups in Google App-Maker when the popup height is larger than the screen size.

Comment: can you please attach any screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving static hight of around 500 and overflow: auto to the popup.